# How actually we can monitor WSO2 EMM using CEP or BAM?

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I am new with wso2 products. I am using EMM for device and app. But i want to monitor my devices continuously.

As some document suggest, i can done this using CEP in real time and also can use BAM. But i did not found any proper document to install or configure these system together (EMM, CEP, BAM).

My EMM server is already live. I am now tring to analysis the http access log to find out registration failed or other error.

But I actually need to monitor the EMM server in real time. 

Do I need to run these servers separately and also have to configure them separately? Is there any way to merge all(EMM,CEP,BAM and even ESS) application and run all of them by running one carbon server?

If I need to run these server separately, then how I can configure CEP/BAM as this will monitor EMM server's API/log files/services etc? 

Is there documentation for this? I can not find any document related to CEP/BAM related to EMM.

Can any one please help me for this?

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 BAM product has been replaced by WSO2 DAS (Data Analytics Server). Again WSO2 DAS consist with WSO2 CEP features where as it is capable of doing both real time and batch time processing. Therefore you can DAS for both batch processing and real time processing

Both DAS and CEP deals with event streams where as in DAS streams could be persisted to event tables as data needs to be stored for batch processing [2]. On the other hand both can be integrated with other applications by using Receivers for streams. You can protocols such as thrift, soap, http, mqtt, jms and kafka when creating receivers[3]

For real time processing you need to write Execution Plans [4] which uses Siddhi Query Language [5]. DAS supports Apache spark for batch processing. Both products consist with Analytic dashboard which could be used to visualize real time and persistent data [6].

[1] http://wso2.com/products/data-analytics-server/

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Understanding+Event+Streams+and+Event+Tables

[3] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Configuring+Event+Receivers

[4] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/Creating+a+Standalone+Execution+Plan

[5] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/SiddhiQL+Guide+3.0

[6] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Analytics+Dashboard

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible. You will need to use a data publisher to publish events to DAS.